# Individual plots worked but once added subplot, nothing shows up

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to put together four subplots that are made using pandas.plot() method. When plotting separately, they show up fine as below:

[image]

But once I started using subplot, it became this:

[image]

I know there might be something to do with either naming the plot objects or using pyplot instead of the pandas .plot method, but couldn't figure out after tried different things. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I always do plotting in a much more object oriented fashion to make sure that I have a handle on my subplots

Comment: Right. Can you provide a solution or some specific steps? Thank you @Keith!

Comment: Would you consider swapping out your screenshots for actual code constituting an [`MCVE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Look at the syntax of the second plot here https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_demo.html

Comment: instead of `dem_GDP_HDI_urb.plot()` you should  use `plt.plot()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try also in this way for example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(221)
plt.plot(x,y)

ax = fig.add_subplot(222)
plt.plot(x,z)
...

plt.show()
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot @Giuseppe!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`ax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) argument.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"foo":[4,5,6], "bar":[1,4,2]})

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(4,3))

df.foo.plot(ax=ax1)
df.bar.plot(ax=ax2)
```

[image: plot]